# android studio в group menu в выдвижной шторке (drawer) нет не радиокнопок ни флажков

Tags: android, android-studio

Я хочу иметь group menu в шторке.

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nv_photo"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_photo"
        android:title="Photo" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nv_cam"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_cam"
        android:title="Camera" />
</group>
```

Ожидаю в меню два итема с единственным выбором (или-или), но радиокнопок нет!
Если вменю сделать так (для пробы):

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="all">
```

, то Checkbox-ов тоже, увы, нет!

Если это же меню (с другими ID) вставить не в шторку (drawer), а просто в 
activity, то все работает как надо.

Мой вопро о том как в шторке (drawer) заставить работать групповое меню с
Checkbox-ами или RadioButton-ами ???

Что не так?
What wrong?

Comment: есть библиотека хорошая , погуглите material drawer mike penz примерно так. Там есть такая реализация под чекбоксы

Answer (score 1):

Что бы реализовать чекбоксы и радиобатоны в NavigationDrawer нужно вставить вместо стандартного меню свой кастомный лайаут и вручную открывать\закрывать NavigationDrawer.
Но есть уже готовые реализации

`https://github.com/rudsonlive/NavigationDrawer-MaterialDesign`
`https://github.com/neokree/GoogleNavigationDrawer`
`https://github.com/madcyph3r/AdvancedMaterialDrawer`